# How to delete another user from Firebase using Ionic2

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, ionic2, angularfire2, google-cloud-functions

Have seen lots of entries from the AngularFire2 side on how to delete a current logged in user, but what if you are the current logged in user trying to delete another user? I can't find anything to help me here.

Is it possible to run Admin SDK functions from a Firebase cloud function?

Any other ideas?

Comment: Admin sdk works in Firebase cloud functions.

Comment: Yes !!!!! Thanks for that